# Is an exact-by-nuclear extension of $C^*$-algebras again exact?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, exact-sequence

I know that in general exact-by-exact extensions of $C^*$-algebras need not be exact. Is it true that, if we have a short exact sequence of $C^*$-algebras

$$0 \to I \to A \to B \to 0$$

such that $I$ is exact and $B$ is nuclear, then $A$ is exact?

If it is true, could you give a reference of the result?
If it is false, could you give a counterexample?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have more chances at math overflow with this one

Comment: I gave a completely wrong answer, so I deleted it. Just saying if you're wondering where it went (I'm more tired than I thought today...). Sorry!